# How to prove: if $AB=I$ then $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(B)$ and if $AB=0$ then $\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B)\le n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and if $AB=I_m$, how can I prove that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(B)$ ?

And similarly, if $AB=0$, then $\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B) \le n$.

Comment: What definition of rank do you use?

Comment: @ArnaudD. For column rank, the dimension of the subspace spanned by the columns of matrix A would be the definition. And as you may know, will be the same as the row rank.

Comment: **Hint**: What is the rank of a invertible matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rank}[0]{\text{rank}}$$\newcommand{\nullity}[0]{\text{nullity}}$For the first one, you may use the [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties)
$$
\rank(A B) \le \min (\rank(A), \rank(B)),
$$
which yields
$$\tag{ineq}
m \le \rank(A), \rank(B) \le \min(m, n).
$$

---

For the second one, the image of $B$ must be contained in the kernel of $A$. Considering dimensions, this yields
$$
\rank(B) \le \nullity(A).
$$
Now use [rank-nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) for $A$.

Comment: I completely understood the second one, thanks a lot. But for the first, can you explain a little more specific? I still can't get why rank(A)=rank(B) holds.

Comment: @Bogyeom consider what $\min(m, n)$ can be. What if $n < m$?

Comment: I think I got what you mean. If $m>n$, then $A$ cannot have a right inverse. The fact that $rank(A)=rank(B)=m$ is a little surprising to me, though.

Comment: Your argument is correct - I was thinking in terms of inequalities, i.e. of what happens to (ineq) if $\min(m, n) = n < m$.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of the first inequality? @AndreasCaranti

Comment: @DanilioGregorin just think of the rank as the dimension of the image.